# Use 'this' in Javascript Constructor to access properties

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype, this

I'm using HTML5 to get photo from Webcam. Then I write a Camera object to handle this, as below:

```
function Camera(width) {
    this.video = $("video#videoInput");
    this.canvas= $("#editor");

    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.hasGetUserMedia = function() {/*check camera available*/};

    var errorCallback = function(e) {};
    this.turnOn = function() {
        if (this.hasGetUserMedia()) {
            // Good to go!      
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {        
                this.video[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                //this is video property of Camera
            }, errorCallback);
        } 
    }    
}
var cam = new Camera();
cam.turnOn()
```

But I can access to Camera properties in some methods, example `Camera.turnOn()`. when I use `this.video`, console output `undefined error`. I know `this` in this case means `navigator object`.

So, how do I access to Camera properties inside callback function of another object?

Comment: Where your issue is, *this* references the [*window* object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#window) (an alias of the [global object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) in browsers), not "the navigator object", which is a different object referenced by [*window.navigator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-navigator-object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the reference and pass it to anything where you need it (or just use it directly depending on the scope).

```
var that = this;
someOtherFunction(that);
```

OR:

you can call another function as though it were `this`

```
someotherFunction.call(this);
```

**I would go ahead and cache the reference at the beginning of your function:**

```
function Camera(width) {
  var that = this;
```

then you have it wherever you might need it.

Comment: Thank you! It's simple ^^. someotherFunction.call(this) is useful for reuse function.

Comment: @Davuz `call()` is incredibly helpful when you start dealing with inheritance.

Comment: before ask, I'm try with `navigator.getUserMedia.call(this,...)` but i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: @Davuz changing the `this` pointer in this case is not the safest way to go. I would just cache the reference to `var that` and use it in the callback function. Changing the pointer could mess things up if the function you're calling also needs to refer to itself. Use `call()` when you NEED to change the this pointer, otherwise just use a reference to the other object.

Answer (score 3):

Save a reference to yourself that you can access in the closure:

```
function Camera(width) {
    this.video = $("video#videoInput");
    this.canvas = $("#editor");

    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.hasGetUserMedia = function() {/*check camera available*/
    };

    var errorCallback = function(e) {
    };
    this.turnOn = function() {
        if (this.hasGetUserMedia()) {
            var self = this;
            navigator.getUserMedia({
                video: true
            }, function(stream) {
                self.video[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                //this is video property of Camera
            }, errorCallback);
        }
    }
}

var cam = new Camera();
cam.turnOn()
```

Comment: Oh, solution is simple but very effective! Thank you! //I will accepted for @m59 reputation :D with same answer!

Comment: Rather than *self* I prefer to use something that indicates it references an instance, say `var cam = this`.

Comment: @RobG yeah, `self` makes me think of `this`, so I've always like `that`, since it's a lot like `this`, but lets me know it's the "other" `this`.